# How to use a generated secret inside a yaml file generated by Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a service account token secret:

```
Version: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Values.appName }}-secret
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-api-secret
  annonations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: ...
```

Once applied, a token will be generated and available under `data.token`.

How can I use `data.token` in another helm generated yaml?

Answer (score 0):

When you have the name (i.e. `{{ .Release.Name }}-api-secret`) of the secret, you can refer it from other k8s objects. Most of the time, these are local (same namespace) object references.

#### Use as `env`

```yaml
env:
- name: TOKEN
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ .Release.Name }}-api-secret
      key: token
```

#### Mount in path

```yaml
volumes:
- name: secret-volume
  secret:
    secretName: {{ .Release.Name }}-api-secret
containers:
- name: test-container
  image: demoImage
  volumeMounts:
  - name: secret-volume
    readOnly: true
    mountPath: "/etc/credentials"
```